# UIButton resizes when I change font?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have several UIButtons, I'm trying to bulk change the font for all of them in InterfaceBuilder, but when I change the font, they auto-resize to the original image dimensions instead of what I had them set to, screwing up the layout.  I would like to avoid having to resize and move everything around again any time I change the font.  I could just set the font in a loop in code, but it seems redundant.

Is there a setting to stop this from happening?

Comment: happens to me too - i wonder if its a bug in xcode, similary, everytime i add a resource xcode's default target becomes ipad while i am testing with iphone - i would like to know if there is some settings in xcode?

Comment: I get this all the time as well as blurring of the original font/image. I think it's a bug in Xcode unfortunately. Haven't played around or resized using XCode 4 though so I can't say whether it's been fixed in that version yet.

Comment: I was wondering the same. It's very annoying and it must be a bug.

Comment: Try to set the frame size for the button programatically when changing the font... At least until they figure out if it is a bug or a "feature". Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This issue doesn't seem to occur in Xcode 4.0 or above.

Should anyone still be using a lesser version of Xcode I would suggest updating.